# jQuery animation images flicker on iPad

Tags: jquery, ajax, ipad, transition, flicker

When I get some images via POST in jQuery, and create a gallery with simple slide effect on the run, every image in that gallery is flickering on transition.

Just want to emphasize that whole website is loaded into single page so maybe there can be a problem with iPad memory.

On PC and MAC everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that this can be used to prevent images to flicker on iPad

```
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)
```

A that helped me, but in asynchronous way (after AJAX responce)

```
$(".ajax-images").css("-webkit-transform","translate3d(0,0,0)");
```